# Laptop HDD failing? Can I repair it?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery, repair

**I have already backed up my HDD.**

Questions:

1. Has it already corrupt data stored on it?
2. Can I repair it and if yes how?
3. If I repair it, can I trust data from that HDD?

---

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskInfo 7.7.0 (C) 2008-2018 hiyohiyo
                                Crystal Dew World : https://crystalmark.info/
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    OS : Windows 8.1 Enterprise [6.3 Build 9600] (x64)
  Date : 2018/08/28 14:45:05

-- Controller Map ----------------------------------------------------------
 + Intel(R) 7 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller [ATA]
   - SAMSUNG HN-M101MBB
   - MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8C0
 + DTSCSIDRV IDE Controller [SCSI]
   - LEZGZ LA7OPQ70DA SCSI CdRom Device
 - Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller [SCSI]

-- Disk List ---------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) SAMSUNG HN-M101MBB : 1000.2 GB [0/0/0, pd1]

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) SAMSUNG HN-M101MBB
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : SAMSUNG HN-M101MBB
        Firmware : 2AR10001
   Serial Number : 
       Disk Size : 1000.2 GB (8.4/137.4/1000.2/1000.2)
     Buffer Size : 8192 KB
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 1953525168
   Rotation Rate : 5400 RPM
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version : ATA8-ACS
   Minor Version : ATA8-ACS version 6
   Transfer Mode : SATA/300 | SATA/300
  Power On Hours : 13220 hours
  Power On Count : 2852 count
     Temperature : 44 C (111 F)
   Health Status : Bad
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, AAM, 48bit LBA, NCQ
       APM Level : 0080h [OFF]
       AAM Level : FE00h [OFF]
    Drive Letter : C:

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 __1 __1 _51 0000000081C3 Read Error Rate
02 252 252 __0 000000000000 Throughput Performance
03 _86 _86 _25 000000001172 Spin-Up Time
04 _98 _98 __0 000000000B33 Start/Stop Count
05 252 252 _10 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count
07 252 252 _51 000000000000 Seek Error Rate
08 252 252 _15 000000000000 Seek Time Performance
09 100 100 __0 0000000033A4 Power-On Hours
0A 252 252 _51 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
0B _94 _94 __0 00000000183D Recalibration Retries
0C _98 _98 __0 000000000B24 Power Cycle Count
B5 _94 _94 __0 000008ECC43D Vendor Specific
BF 100 100 __0 000000000398 G-Sense Error Rate
C0 252 252 __0 000000000000 Power-off Retract Count
C2 _56 _47 __0 00350006002C Temperature
C3 100 100 __0 000000000000 Hardware ECC recovered
C4 252 252 __0 000000000000 Reallocation Event Count
C5 100 100 __0 000000000001 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 252 252 __0 000000000000 Uncorrectable Sector Count
C7 100 100 __0 000000000002 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
C8 100 100 __0 000000004623 Write Error Rate
DF _94 _94 __0 00000000183D Load/Unload Retry Count
E1 _79 _79 __0 0000000352E8 Load/Unload Cycle Count
```

Answer (score 1):

> Has it already corrupt data stored on it?

That is unknown. You would have to somehow verify your backups to know for sure. Perhaps by comparing files that you know should not have changed between your latest backup and an older one, if you have more than one backup.

The fact that "Reallocated Sectors Count", "Seek Error Rate", "Reallocation Event Count" and "Uncorrectable Sector Count" are all above the threshold give me some hope that any data you have managed to actually get out of that HDD is maybe correct... but the fact that the raw values for those attributes are all zeroes makes me think this disk might not actually track those attributes at all.

The S.M.A.R.T values (Current/Worst/Threshold) are scaled so that bigger value = better. The only value that is below threshold is the Read Error Rate, and that is *way* below the threshold value, meaning that the drive is detecting a clearly unacceptable amount of low-level read errors.

This page seems to have two informative YouTube videos about HDD fault diagnostics (while also marketing their data recovery services):

https://outsourcedatarecovery.com/hn-m101mbb-repair/

> Can I repair it and if yes how?

This is one of the questions where "if you need to ask, the answer is no". If you had a cleanroom-style dust-free workstation and access to the necessary tools, spare parts and HDD-vendor-specific knowledge, you would not be asking this question.

The only real HDD repair a hobbyist could do is swapping the circuit board of a HDD. As mentioned in the videos on the page I linked above, the replacement circuit board must be from the exact same model HDD, with the same firmware level.

In the video, three groups of HDDs were identified regarding this type of repair:

- HDDs where you can just replace the circuit board with no extra steps needed (usually older HDDs)
- HDDs which require moving a memory chip from the bad circuit board to the replacement board (because the chip contains the HDD serial number and possibly calibration data that is unique to those particular mechanical parts of the drive). This requires surface-mount soldering skills & tools.
- HDDs where the unique data is stored within one of the large controller chips. These can be impossible with hobbyist resources, as you'll need the tools and knowledge to reprogram the controller or other solutions.

Also, this HDD has been powered on for at least 13220 hours. Since this is a laptop HDD, if we assume that it has been powered on average 8 hours on every day, that means it is more than 4 years old. HDDs are wear items, and this one is, if not already completely worn out, at least very close to it. So it is not going to be worth much effort to try repairing this one, especially if you already have a backup.

The only sensible reason for trying to repair this HDD would be to rescue some valuable data that is not backed up elsewhere.

> If I repair it, can I trust data from that HDD?

The mechanical precision required with HDDs is so great and new HDDs are so inexpensive that I would treat a professionally-repaired HDD as nothing more than a  temporary fix that hopefully allows the data to be rescued. I would not keep using a HDD that is over 3 years old and already failed once, no matter how professionally the repair was done.

Besides, replacing an aging HDD in a laptop with a SSD is awesome: not only will SSD be much faster, it is also insensitive to rough handling, which is an important factor with laptops.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like add to the answer provided as it's very common while the question was direct and detailed. 
As per SMART you provided:

- 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count,
- 000000000000 Seek Error Rate,
- 000000000000 Hardware ECC recovered,
- 000000000000 Reallocation Event Count
- 000000000000 Reallocation Event Count
- 000000000001 Current Pending Sector Count
- 000000000000 Uncorrectable Sector Count
- 000000000002 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
- 00000004623 Write Error Rate

your HDD is OK.
There are no damaged sectors on it and sectors relocation didn't happen. There were some write errors most likely they are related to the magnetic heads themselves or other physical reasons, but the number of errors is still acceptable.

As was said your drive is working for at least 4 years. As per my statistics most of the drive die on the first 1-2 years or slightly degrade after 6+ years. I have a bunch of HDDs working for 10+ years but taht depends on the usage conditions (temperature, vibration, mounting).

As far I can say that your HDD is operatable and no signs of data loss as per details you provided.

*That doesn't mean that you don't have partition system issues and files damage of the logical level!*

So, I strongly urge you from physically opening the HDD. This must be done only in special clean lab rooms by data recovery staff and only when magnetic heads or disks are damaged inside and need to be extracted.

You definitely doesn't have controller and HDD firmware issues, otherwise it would not be detected and you would fail to read SMART from the drive.

SO, to conclude, you might have only data structure issues caused by file system problems that you can check with **chkdsk** or similar tools. If you need lost data recovery - you can use free utilities like [GetDataBack](https://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm), [Recuuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) or [EaseUS](https://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/recover-formatted-partition.htm).